# App interaction with Accessibility service

Tags: android

I'm wondering if it's possible to automate some actions via accessibility action. According to the Android documentation the app can call `performAction` using an `AccessibilityNodeInfo` but there is a note: An action can be performed only if the request is made from an AccessibilityService. Does it mean that this action can be done in the context of the call `onAccessibilityEvent()` only? If I bind from activity to the service to execute an action, does it work? If not, the only solution I see is to push commands toward the service and execute it at first call of `onAccessibilityEvent()`, am I missing anything?

Comment: this question did not worth a bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets clear some points :

> An accessibility service can be configured to receive specific types
>   of accessibility events, listen only to specific packages, get events
>   from each type only once in a given time frame, retrieve window
>   content, specify a settings activity, etc.

and basically `onAccessibilityEvent()` is the Callback for AccessibilityEvents.

So Lets say this service is just listener with specific permissions to do specific action like for example  `AccessibilityEvent.getSource()` which will return `AccessibilityNodeInfo` .

**Can I excute actions (invoke) based on this listener ?**

**Answer : yes , ofcourse you can.**

Comment: So I can work only in the onAccessibilityEvent() context, right? And can I execute several actions on different screen? I mean: push a button that open an activity, paste text on the second activity and so on. Or do I need to listen to the second activity?

Comment: @greywolf82 did not get that part well , yes you can push a button that open an activity , but did not get the second activity part , please be more clear so i can help you :)

Comment: I need to do several action in sequence. I don't understand if I can create a unique sequence of actions inside the callback or I need to wait each event, example: I need to push a button on activity1 and then paste some text on activity2. In order to do the paste action, do I need to wait that the second activity is in foreground? I guess when the activity2 is in foreground I receive a new callback. In this case I need a "state machine", first call -> operaton1, second call -> operation2 and so on.

Comment: if actions dont depend on each other you can do asynchronous calls each you will have to create a queue.

Comment: @ProllyGeek : Hi, i am using AccessibilityService and read the other application say "Flipkart". but there i have a problem i got the viewpager at detail page and it returns two or three views continuously but i only need the visible view at a time. But i am not able to get the only visible view. I am using android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked|typeWindowContentChanged"
How can i get the only view of detail page.
Please help

Comment: @ManishAgrawal i would love to help you for sure , but i did not get the question clearly , would you clarify more , or send a code sample please , what do you mean by visible view ? what happens to other three ? whatdos teh p do exactly to hide other views ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek : I need to fetch the name of the product from the flipkart app detail page. Currently I am able to access the layout views whenever the detail page is open. But flipkart detail page contains a viewpager so the problem is whenever i slide the page it gives randomly views of different product but I only need the visible view's layout.